# php - How to correctly POST dynamic fields in Symfony form

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm creating an application to generate test questions, where I can add `N` answers to single question. (I can add these answers via jQuery).
How should I correctly POST this? I have read about Form Events but I don't have any idea how to implement it in this situation.

Here is my current code (I'm using Symfony 4):
**Question** Entity

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\QuestionRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="question")
 */
class Question
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\User", inversedBy="questions")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false, onDelete="CASCADE")
     */
    private $user;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100, nullable=true)
     */
    private $label;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text", length=2000)
     */
    private $content;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=45, options={"default": "single"})
     */
    private $type;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\QuestionAnswer", mappedBy="question")
     */
    private $answers;

    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId(): int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @return User
     */
    public function getUser(): User
    {
        return $this->user;
    }

    /**
     * @param User $user
     */
    public function setUser(User $user): void
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getLabel(): string
    {
        return $this->label;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $label
     */
    public function setLabel(string $label): void
    {
        $this->label = $label;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getContent(): string
    {
        return $this->content;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $content
     */
    public function setContent(string $content): void
    {
        $this->content = $content;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getType(): string
    {
        return $this->type;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $type
     */
    public function setType($type): void
    {
        $this->type = $type;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|QuestionAnswer[]
     */
    public function getAnswers()
    {
        return $this->answers;
    }
}
```

**QuestionAnswer** Entity

```
class QuestionAnswer
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Question", inversedBy="answers")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false, onDelete="CASCADE")
     */
    private $question;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text")
     */
    private $content;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
     */
    private $is_correct;

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getContent(): ?string
    {
        return $this->content;
    }

    public function setContent(string $content): self
    {
        $this->content = $content;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getIsCorrect(): ?bool
    {
        return $this->is_correct;
    }

    public function setIsCorrect(bool $is_correct): self
    {
        $this->is_correct = $is_correct;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return self
     */
    public function getQuestion(): self
    {
        return $this->question;
    }

    /**
     * @param Question $question
     */
    public function setQuestion(Question $question): void
    {
        $this->question = $question;
    }
}
```

Comment: Answer as a array.

Comment: @HeinzSchilling I know to pass it as array but how to properly assign this into DB?

Comment: The best option would be to follow the How to Embed a Collection of Forms http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_collections.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow the documentation:

### [How to Embed a Collection of Forms](http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_collections.html)

Where in your case Question = Task, and QuestionAnswer = Tag.

Answer (score 0):

try to change your code to this and see the difference your self:

in **Question** entity:

```
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
//....

/**
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\QuestionRepository")
* @ORM\Table(name="question")
*/
class Question
{
//....

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\QuestionAnswer")
 * @var answers
 */
private $answers;


public function setAnswers(answers $answers)
{
    $this->answers = $answers;
}

public function getAnswers()
{
    return $this->answers;
}
public function __construct()
{
    $this->answers = new ArrayCollection();
}
}
```

then delete the question field from **QuestionAnswer** entity and update your database schema